# Not Supported Error when testing suspense

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-suspense

I'm getting a strange error when trying to use `react-testing-library` to test `React.Suspense`.  The error just says "Not Supported" but doesn't give any real insight into the problem.  I followed the example that [Kent Dodds did on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfb5jvHq9c4).

I posted the [full code of my problem on github here](https://github.com/benmonro/not-supported-rtl-suspense/tree/master), but here's a snapshot of the test code:

```
import React from "react";

import { render, waitForElement, cleanup } from "react-testing-library";
import MyOtherPackageThing from "my-package/lib/my-thing";
import LazyThing from "../src/index";

afterEach(cleanup);

test("it works", async () => {
  const { getByText, debug } = render(<MyOtherPackageThing />);

  await waitForElement(() => getByText("my thing"));

  expect(getByText("my thing"));
});

describe("these fail with 'Not Supported'", () => {
  test("it lazy loads a local component", async () => {
    const LazyLocalThing = React.lazy(() => import("../src/LocalThing"));
    const { getByText, debug } = render(
      <React.Suspense fallback="Loading...">
        <LazyLocalThing />
      </React.Suspense>
    );
    debug();
    await waitForElement(() => getByText("my local thing"));
    debug();
    expect(getByText("my local thing"));
  });

  test("it says not supported, like wtf", async () => {
    const { getByText, debug } = render(<LazyThing />);
    debug();
    await waitForElement(() => getByText("my thing"));
    debug();
    expect(getByText("my thing"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share more details about an issue? I have some errors, when trying `yarn jest` in `my-consumer-pkg`, I can see some long log. And maybe you should open an issue in that testing package, cause it will be hard to find help here, this is highly specialized question.

Comment: @zishe sure, what would you like to know?  The code in github has a readme on how to reproduce.  I put everything in a `run.sh` so you shouldn't have any problems setting it up.

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/benmonro/not-supported-rtl-suspense/issues/1 , I don't see any `run.sh` file.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error recently.  I noticed that Kent's working sample was using `create-react-app` and wondered if it was Babeling something special for Node/Jest.  As a result of using CRA, his `package.json` uses the babel preset `react-app`.

Try installing and configuring the plugin `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` (which is the specific part of the `react-app` preset I think we need).  I believe this plugin transforms dynamic imports into `require` statements for Node.  More info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node

install the plugin:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node
```

in my-consumer-pkg/babel.config.js, add the plugin:

```
plugins: [
    ...
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node"
]
```

...this should be enough to get past the `Not Supported` error.

As an aside, I noticed that one of your tests named "it lazy loads a local component" was subsequently failing with this error:

```
Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: [object Object]. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.
```

...so I made a minor change so that the `LocalThing` was a function

```
const LocalThing = () => <div>my local thing</div>;
```